# How to use database in windows forms application

Tags: c#, database, windows-runtime, database-connection, local-database

I cant add service-based database to my project (wforms application) it says that

`"SQL server should be configured to allow remote connections. provider: SQL network interfaces, error: 52 - unable to locate a local databse runtime installation. verify that sql server is installed and that local database runtime feature is enabled.`"

So as said, i installed sql server 2008. I was able to add database but i cant access the tables, etc. I was afraid that i might mess up everything that's why i uninstall it for a moment and hoping to know the 'proper installing of it the next time. How am it going to fix it, i am new to using database that's why i dont know how to fix such 'names instances.. A help is really appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for noticing. At first it showed an error saying 'sql server 2008/2005 should be installed' so i searched over the net and have 2008 be installed. But after installing, yes I was able to add database on my project but when i try to click on the panels of tables, etc. I can't access them. I cant post image so this what happened - it says it could not load file or assembly ... the system could not find the file specified.' I dont know what it refers to coz im new to it.